# Oracle APEX before insert trigger issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a before insert trigger in Oracle Application Express to fill out the timetaken field by calculating enddate - startdate that the user will enter in the web application. The table looks like this:

Column Name Data Type
ID          NUMBER
STARTDATE   TIMESTAMP(6)
ENDDATE     TIMESTAMP(6)
TIMETAKEN   TIMESTAMP(6)

What I am trying to do is this:

```
create or replace trigger "TESTS_T1"
before
insert or update on "TESTS"
for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TESTS VALUES (id, :new.startdate, :new.enddate, new:timetaken:= :new.enddate - :new.startdate);
END;
```

But I am getting this error when I try to enter a row:

error ORA-04098: trigger 'MAIN.TESTS_T1' is invalid and failed re-validation

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, not exactly like that. When you subtract two timestamps, you don't get yet another timestamp as result (which is what `timetaken`'s datatype suggests), but `interval day to second`.

Apart from that, trigger should contain only the calculation - all the other columns are inserted (or updated) in "main" transaction.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tests
  2  (
  3     id          NUMBER,
  4     startdate   TIMESTAMP (6),
  5     enddate     TIMESTAMP (6),
  6     timetaken   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND    --> this
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_biu_tests
  2     BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  3     ON tests
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :new.timetaken := :new.enddate - :new.startdate;
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO tests (id, startdate, enddate)
  2       VALUES (1, SYSTIMESTAMP, SYSTIMESTAMP - 2);

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tests;

        ID STARTDATE                      ENDDATE                        TIMETAKEN
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 06.07.22 12:24:48,665450       04.07.22 12:24:48,000000       -02 00:00:00.665450
```

Or:

```
SQL> SELECT id,
  2         EXTRACT (DAY FROM timetaken) days,
  3         EXTRACT (HOUR FROM timetaken) hours,
  4         EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM timetaken) minutes,
  5         EXTRACT (SECOND FROM timetaken) seconds
  6    FROM tests;

        ID       DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         -2          0          0    -,66545

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried what you suggested but when I tried to enter the row I got this error:
`Error at line 2/16: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903


1. INSERT INTO tests2 (id, startdate, enddate)
2.        VALUES (id, SYSTIMESTAMP, SYSTIMESTAMP - 2);`

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Can't tell what, though. Where exactly did you try to insert that row? Could you post the screenshot?

Comment: I figured what I did wrong. Thank you very much! 
Now I am wondering how can I create the charts in APEX using hours, minutes and seconds. I can just select only one field? Should I create another question?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you should open a new question as that's a new problem.

Comment: I have just created it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901404/create-chart-in-apex-and-add-the-average-function-considering-hours-minutes-and